# javax.mail.Transport.send0() not throwing the exceptions it's promising

Tags: java, email, exception

when i'm sending an email to a false domain, say to `test@rstjhajh.com`, i'm receiving and **email** to the sender address, with message body:

```
The following message to <test@rstjhajh.com> was undeliverable.
The reason for the problem:
5.1.2 - Bad destination host 'DNS Hard Error looking up rstjhajh.com (MX):  NXDomain'
```

and an attachment

```
Reporting-MTA: dns; ironport2-out.teksavvy.com

Final-Recipient: rfc822;test@rstjhajh.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.0.0 (permanent failure)
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 5.1.2 - Bad destination host 'DNS Hard Error looking up rstjhajh.com (MX):  NXDomain' (delivery attempts: 0)
```

`Transport.send()` is **not** throwing any exceptions.

How is that possible??? a naive Q. but burned my time & there it is.

TIA.

//============

EDIT:

`rstjhajh.com` is not a registered DNS server. There's no email server to accept and hand-shake on it - when i look it up on DNS, i'm getting a `NamingException`. to whose "door" is `Transport.send()` delivering it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because mail is an asynchronous protocol. `Transport.send()` throws an exception if the e-mail can not be sent to the mail server or if that mail server rejects it (unknown host for example).

What is happening here is that the e-mail is correctly sent to (and accepted by) the mail server, but that server can not deliver it because the e-mail address does not exist.

You can not rely on `Transport.send()` throwing exceptions to determine if the e-mail you sent was correctly delivered. The only way is to check the address that was used to send it for undelivered messages.

Comment: `Transport.send()`is sending the e-mail to whatever host you configured the mail session with. Can you show the code where you configure your Session and Message objects ?

Comment: got it - turns out overlooked one thing.